# Fetch current month data of string date column

Tags: mysql

I have a `string` column for date in my database, I want to fetch all records of current month. my date format is like (18/06/2019 11:03 AM)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (date_column between  STR_TO_DATE(CURDATE() ,'%01/m%/Y') AND CURDATE() )
```

Comment: It is not a good practice to store dates as string. Take a look a the MONTH() date function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date You can use it make a condition on the month part of the date, e.g. `WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(date_column)) = 'x'`

Comment: You should try and figure that out yourself. I suggest you first print out the results using the MONTH function w/o any condition. It should be easy from there...

Comment: @marekful I used MONTH function like `SELECT MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(date_column)) FROM table` it is giving error `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1582 Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'STR_TO_DATE' in`

Comment: @Dishko Try this query : ```SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTH(CURDATE()) = MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(date_column, "%d/%m/%Y %i:%h %p"));```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query :

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTH(CURDATE()) = MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(date_column, "%d/%m/%Y"));
```